# add rows - adding three times when click a button for one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code that create a dynamica rows when user clicks add row button in popup window. There are two different flow in my code.
1. When user click a row on parent window, a servlet will be called and see whether data present in table1,if its present then populate the same in pop up window as read only form
2.When user click a row on parent window, a servlet will be called and see whether data present in table1,if its not present then it get the data from table2 and populate the same in pop up window as user editable form (on few field).

now i am facing strange experience

```js
  //script for addrow button
    $('html, #addrow').click(function(e) {
   //  alert("i am aa");
     $('#tab_logic tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" list="inppara" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="inppara"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option><option value="Operation Check">Operation Check</option><option value="Ext.Apperance">Ext.Apperance</option><option value="Verify TC">Verify TC</option><option value="Material">Material</option><option value="Dimension Check">Dimension Check</option><option value="Threads Check">Threads Check</option><option value="Visual Check">Visual Check</option><option value="Specification">Specification</option><option value="Batch no">Batch no</option><option value="Mfg.Date">Mfg.Date</option><option value="Exp.Date">Exp.Date</option></datalist><td><input type="text" list="inpsepci" id="inpspec" ><datalist id="inpsepci"><option value="AsperPO">AsperPO</option><option value="Damage">Damage</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="Stainless Steel">Stainless Steel</option><option value="Gaues">Gaues</option><option value="Mild Steel">Mild Steel</option><option value="As per Drawing">As per Drawing</option><option value="Cast Iron">Cast Iron</option><option value="Copper">Copper</option><option value="Aluminium">Aluminium</option><option value="Brass">Brass</option><option value="Spring Steel">Spring Steel</option><option value="Tool Steel">Tool Steel</option><option value="Nylon">Nylon</option><option value="CRGO">CRGO</option><option value="EN1">EN1</option><option value="EN2">EN2</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act1" id="inpact10" class="tb3"><datalist id="act1"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act2" id="inpact20" class="tb3"><datalist id="act2"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act3" id="inpact30" class="tb3"><datalist id="act3"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act4" id="inpact40" class="tb3"><datalist id="act4"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><input type="text" list="act5" id="inpact50" class="tb3"><datalist id="act5"><option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist></td><td><img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del"></td></tr>');
     // add code here
   });
```

```js
$.ajax({
   url : 'PopulateTable2',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify({"inspinp" :inspinp}),
         contentType: 'application/json',
         mimeType: 'application/json',
   success : function(responseJson) {   
    if(responseJson!=null){
     if(responseJson && responseJson[0] && responseJson[0].actual1) {
      // find reponseJson as actual values; if found, then made that as read only(i.e., inspection data exist)
      $("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
      $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['parameters']);
        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['specifications']);
        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['actual1']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['actual2']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['actual3']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['actual4']); 
        rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['actual5']); 
        rowNew.appendTo(tableinsp);
        }); 
      $("#addrow").hide();
      $("#save").hide();
     }else {
      // else, received response only criteria from QC_CRITERIA table and made it as user editable form
      $("#tab_logic").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      var tableinsp = $("#tab_logic");
      $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['parameters']);
        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['specifications']);
        rowNew.children().eq(2).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact10" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
        rowNew.children().eq(3).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact20" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
        rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact30" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
        rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact40" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
        rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text" list="combo-options" id="inpact50" class="tb3"> <datalist id="combo-options"> <option value="YES">YES</option><option value="NO">NO</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option></datalist>');
        rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<img src="delete.gif" height="42" width="42" alt="idata" class="del">');
        rowNew.appendTo(tableinsp);
        }); 
      $("#addrow").show();
      $("#save").show();
     }
     return false;
    }
   }
     });
```

```js
//script for close button
    $('html, .popup-btn-close').click(function(e) {
     $('.popup').hide();
     $('.page-cover').detach();
     window.opener.location.reload();
   });
```

1. when i directly enter into (2) method that ie no data in table 1 so get in table 2. in that way when i click add row button , one row will be added after last row
2. **Otherwise from parent window --> click row --> call servlet --> row exist in table1 --> get correct data in pop up as read only. close popup --> return to parent window -> modify some i/p --> click on the same row --> call servlet--> no data in table1 --> so get the data from table2 --> populate in popup as editable --> now when i click add row, there are three additional rows are adding.**

So please help me on this strange issue.

Comment: because you add a row for each existing row (click event first code sample)

Comment: @Ash: Thanks!. but  how its correctly working on first flow as i mentioned. Please help me for better understanding